# Is there API documentation available for DXA? Where can I find it?

Tags: dxa

I'm looking for the DXA API documentation. For example, in a layout I can see

```
<script src="@Url.VersionedContent("/assets/scripts/main.js")"></script>
```

But when I search for `VersionedContent` in the "docs" site, I don't find it.

[image]

I can see that the API has documentation markup; for example, here is [the source for VersionedContent](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/master/Sdl.Web.Mvc/Html/UrlHelperExtensions.cs#L25).

Is this documentation available as a compiled CHM, or some other easily consumable form? Where should I look to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We haven't generated any API documentation up till now, since indeed as you mention the source code is documented and available.

It is on the backlog to create API documentation, either in a Microsoft Compiled HTML Help (CHM) format, or maybe even better to create it online MSDN like? But at current we focus our development effort on finishing the framework, since the source code is documented and readily available. I follow this article there http://tim-stanley.com/post/msdn-style-class-documentation/ where it states: Code Is The Documentation, and API documents can be replaced by IntelliSense and the Go To Definition.

So in short, where should you look, well right now in Visual Studio, using IntelliSense, or if you wish, go to GitHub.

Comment: All I get from "intellisense" is the information that can be obtained by reflection against the DLLs. In this case, just the names and types of the parameters. It may be possible to get more information by building the framework with /doc and then placing the resulting XML in a suitable place. As things stand, the Visual Studio approach isn't effective.

Comment: The doc XML files for DXA Framework assemblies are available as part of the DXA distribution. If you copy those to your dev. environment, you should get better Intellisense support.

Comment: I hadn't found them in the distribution, so yesterday I blogged about how to generate them and copy them to the dev environment. https://blog.indivirtual.nl/getting-dxa-api-documentation-display-visual-studio/

Comment: @DominicCronin looking at the DXA 1.5 download I indeed seem to be missing the `.xml` files, so it seems they were lost in the build/package process. I'll report it as an issue so we can make sure they are there again in the 1.6 release.